# How define relation hasManyThrough

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, orm, relationship

I have tables:

```
users
 - id
 - name
 - company_id
companies
 - id
 - company_name
watched_objects
 - id
 - user_id
 - object_id
 - type
```

Now I want to get all watched companies for a user.

So query should looks:

```
SELECT
  companies.*
FROM companies
  JOIN watched_objects ON watched_objects.object_id = companies.id
WHERE watched_objects.user_id = 1
```

How should I define relations?

I try this:

```
class User
{
    public function watched()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Company', 'App\WatchedObject', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

But query is:

```
SELECT
  companies.*,
  watched_objects.user_id
FROM companies
  INNER JOIN watched_objects ON watched_objects.id = companies.id
WHERE watched_objects.user_id = 1
```

How I can change `watched_objects.id` to `watched_objects.object_id`.

Comment: I usually go for a database view in that case, especially if you want to fetch these data quite often (and I suspect you will)

Comment: View is not what I want to archive. This approach makes mess in app, I won't mix different database layers.

Comment: You could show your eloquent query, but shooting  `return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Company', 'App\WatchedObject', 'user_id', 'id')->where('type','=','company');`

Comment: @cssBlaster21895 where in your example is implemented relation `watched_objects.object_id = companies.id`?

Comment: I was just guessing, that adding a part of a query will get all objects but add also filter on type,to get only companies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your treating object_id as company id, then the relation is considered to be many to many. Then table watched_objects will be the third table kept the relation of user and company.

```
class User {
    public function watched() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Company', 'watched_objects', 'user_id', 'object_id');
    }
}
```

In order to find the watched companies of user 1, you can use the following code.

```
$watched_companies = User::find(1)->watched;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all watched companies by a user you can do  like this:

```
$watches=WatchedObject::where(['user_id'=>Auth::user()->id])->with('company')->get();
foreach($watches as $watch)
{
     print_r($watch->company->company_name);
}
```

**Relation:**
Company hasMany watched objects:

```
public function watches()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\WatchedObject','object_id'); 
}
```

and belongsTo in watchedObject Model:

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Company','object_id');
}
```

Comment: Your example is ok, I know I can figure it as you show. But is any way to do it using relations mechanism? Eg. like in in Ralis http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association in rails this works perfectly. It seems in Laravel relations are poor-implemented...